# Why char specified as integer in printf gets printed correctly

Tags: c, types, type-conversion, printf, stdio

Why does the following code work?

```
char c = 'A';
printf("%d - size: %d", c, sizeof(c));
```

Prints out:

```
65 - size: 1
```

Why is the output not garbage, since an int would usually be 4 bytes long and we can clearly see that the char is 1 byte long. 
Does the compiler do the implicit conversation?

Comment: Because integer promotion.

Comment: It works because of integer promotion rules - however, you should probably use `%hhd` (or `%hhu` for `unsigned char`).

Comment: 'A' is just another way of writing the integer 65. It happens that 65 fits nicely inside the limits of type "char", so conversion loses no data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special rule for functions with variable-length argument lists, like `printf`.  In the variable-length portion of the argument list, all integral arguments smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`, and `float` is promoted to `double`.  So it turns out it's perfectly fine to print a character (or a `short`) using `%d`.

These *default argument promotions* end up accounting for a number of anomalies in `printf`.  You might think that the correct format specifiers for `char`, `short`, `int`, `float`, and `double` are `%hhd`, `%hd`, `%d`, `%f`, and `%lf`, respectively.  But in fact you can get away with `%d`, `%d`, `%d`, `%f`, and `%f`.  `printf` basically ignores the `l` modifier for floating point, and it seems to ignore the `h` modifier for integers.  (Actually `h` can make a difference in obscure cases, as chux explains in a comment.)

Comment: The `"h"` modifier cases the `int` argument (regardless it was originally `int`, `short`, `signed char`) to be converted to `short` before printing.  The `"hh"` modifier cases the `int` argument to be converted to `signed char` before printing. So "essentially ignore" is true if the original value passed was in range of the finite  converted type.

Comment: @chux "essentially ignore" was a bit too string.  Reworded.

Comment: Is there any documentation of this special rule?

Comment: @NightRain23 Yes.  They are called the *default argument promotions*; a web search should find more details.

Answer (score 5):

Any integer type with a rank lower than `int` is **promoted** to either `int` or `unsigned int` anytime it is used in an expression.  This is specified in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the C standard:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than int or unsigned int ) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less  than
>     or  equal  to  the  rank  of int and unsigned int .
> - A bit-field of type
>     _Bool , int , signed int ,or unsigned int .
>
> If  an int can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as 
>   restricted  by  the  width,  for  a bit-field),  the  value  is 
>   converted  to  an int ; otherwise,  it  is  converted  to  an unsigned
>   int . These  are  called  the integer promotions .
>
> All  other  types  are  unchanged  by  the integer promotions

That's what is happening in this case, since the `printf` function doesn't implicitly know the type of its parameters at compile time.  So the `char` argument is promoted to `int`, and using `%d` to format it is valid.

Comment: Any integer type with a rank lower than `int` is promoted to `int` **if** `int` can hold all values of the type. Otherwise, it's promoted to `unsigned int`. For example, if `unsigned short` and `unsigned int` are the same size, then `unsigned short` promotes to `unsigned int`, not to `int`. (That won't matter for `char` except on exotic systems where `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, which can only happen if `CHAR_BIT >= 16`.)